# How to hide auto-generated comments?

Tags: radare2

When disassembling in Radare2, the output is decorated with random annotations of memory peeks, decimal conversions, etc., for example:

```
...
0000:06ea      and al, 0x7f
0000:06ec      cmp al, 5                                   ; 5
0000:06ee      jne 0x712
0000:06f0      mov eax, dword [bx + 8]                     ; [0x8:4]=-1 ; 8
0000:06f4      mov edx, dword [bp + 0x14]                  ; [0x14:4]=-1 ; 20
...
```

I find them largely irrelevant: for example, I don't care about the value at `0x14` when that is used as a displacement rather than a fixed address. What command do I use to hide them, either globally or for a particular address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible [since version 3.0](https://github.com/radare/radare2/releases/tag/3.0.0). The commands are:

```
e asm.comments=false
e asm.usercomments=true
```

The former turns all comments off and the latter overrides this for user-added comments. Currently there's no finer distinction than this: you can't turn off the `[0x8:4]=-1` keeping the decimal conversions only, for example.